# How to search via data attribute based on a numeric value and get the closest value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a unordered list of divs with different `data-score` values. What I am trying to access the first div with `data-score` just above the value of the searched value. I have the following code, but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

```js
var userscore = $("#userScore").val();

var next = $("div[data-score >=" + userscore + "]").text();

$("#result").text(next);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="userScore" value="20">
<div data-score="5" class="item">A</div>
<div data-score="15" class="item">B</div>
<div data-score="45" class="item">E</div>
<div data-score="25" class="item">C</div>
<div data-score="35" class="item">D</div>


<div id="result">NEXT IS UNKNOWN!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.filter()` to reduce set of elements as per the `condition` specified in the handler.

Apply `.sort()` over elements returned by `.filter` and get the `.first()` element out of it!

```js
var userscore = $("#userScore").val();
var next = $("div[data-score]").filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('score') >= userscore;
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return Number($(a).data('score')) - Number($(b).data('score'));
}).first();

$("#result").text(next.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="userScore" value="20">
<div data-score="5" class="item">A</div>
<div data-score="15" class="item">B</div>
<div data-score="45" class="item">E</div>
<div data-score="25" class="item">C</div>
<div data-score="35" class="item">D</div>
<hr>
<div id="result">NEXT IS UNKNOWN!</div>
```

Comment: thanks! when I search for 20, it should only bring C (with the closest but greater data-score value), how can I do this?